# contextconfiguration outside of test

Tags: spring, autowired

After following an example, this works for JUnit testing:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring/context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@Transactional  
public class ServiceTest  {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
    assertEquals(0, service.getNumber()); ...
    }
```

When I try to move this into non-test code, this does NOT work:

```
// @ContextConfiguration only works for testing (JUnit).  What do I use here, instead?  
// @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring/helloWorldContext.xml")  
@Service // supposedly to get the Spring Container to 'see' this class
public class Accessor {      
    @Autowired( required=true )      
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    public Accessor() {
    return service.getNumber(); ...
    }
```

Basically, I want to use the non-test class in the same way that I use the test class.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I need the same as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable annotation-config by adding this to your spring configuration file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Documention:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do it for regular bean, but you can create `@Configuration` class and put it alongside your bean instead:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring/context.xml")
public class ServiceConfiguration {}
```